# Backup of procedures in toad oracle 12.1?

Tags: oracle, toad, oracle12c

Procedure for taking backup of procedures in toad oracle 12.1? I would also like to ask the difference between procedures and stored procedures

Comment: Also, if possible attach a link for getting complete knowledge regarding toad for oracle 12.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between stored procedure and standalone procedure in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286156/what-is-the-difference-between-stored-procedure-and-standalone-procedure-in-orac)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I hate to say it, but IMHO, your question is a bad fit for SO  because
- you're asking two questions in one post
- one of your questions is off-topic (we're not here to give you a user manual for TOAD)
- the other question is a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

> I would also like to ask the difference between procedures and stored procedures

A procedure is a subprogram that performs a specific action.

Oracle's documentation for [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_procedure.htm) uses the term "standalone procedure" rather than "stored procedure" (but does state that it is stored in the db):

> A standalone procedure is a procedure (a subprogram that performs a specific action) that is stored in the database.

A [nested procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/procedure.htm#i35564) is a procedure that is in a PL/SQL block or a package.

From the [`CREATE PACKAGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_package.htm#i2091914) documentation:

> The CREATE PACKAGE statement creates or replaces the specification for a stored package, which is an encapsulated collection of related procedures, functions, and other program objects stored as a unit in the database. The package specification declares these objects. The package body, specified subsequently, defines these objects.

Standalone procedures and procedures nested in a package are both stored (compiled) within the database - so are "stored" procedures. Procedures defined in an anonymous PL/SQL block are "nested" procedures but are not "stored" procedures.

This anonymous block defines a procedure which is not a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE
  n NUMBER := 1;

  PROCEDURE incr( a IN OUT NUMBER ) IS
  BEGIN
    a := a + 1;
  END;
BEGIN
  incr(n);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(n);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Toad has many ways to export that can be used to make backups of your objects. See the Database menu, Export sub-menu. Export DDL allows you to retrieve DDL for specific objects. Generate Schema Script will generate a complete script necessary to recreate an entire schema. You can also create actions for these tasks in the Automation Designer, available from the Utilities menu. Those actions can be scheduled. You can also add actions to zip the results, move them to another location (folder, ftp, email, etc.) You can create an "app" that will export the objects, zip the results, move them to another location, and email you when complete. There are many possibilities.